# Activation problem: "Unable to connect to the internet"

Tags: installation, licensing, internet

I am trying to install Math 13.2 on a Mac running Mojave.  I have access to Mathematica through my institution and in the past have been able to "activate" the app by simply entering my institutional credentials.  However when I open the fully installed App, I get the message "Unable to connect to the internet", and the option to do an institutional login is disabled.  (Of course the internet connection is fine as can be verified via a browser window etc.)  When I try to manually activate, Wolfram generates a key and password from my machine ID, but these too are rejected by the app.

Any suggestions??

Comment: I believe this question can be routed to [Wolfram Support](https://support.wolfram.com/) for resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Solution turns out to be:  rm /Library/Mathematica and ~/Library/Mathematica completely.  Then retry activation.  This is not an internet connection problem, it is a bug with refreshing SSO and activation data from previous versions.